# sql statements equality?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm just trying to figure out whether these statements are equal or not:

```
SELECT *
FROM houses LEFT JOIN tenants on houses.id= tenants.id
WHERE houses.id = 005 and tenants.address = '1 chavvy road'

SELECT *
FROM houses LEFT JOIN tenants on houses.id= tenants.id and tenants.address='1 chavvy road'
WHERE houses.id = 005
```

I created a dummy database and it looks like they're equivalent. Can anyone think of an example when these are not equivalent?

My understanding is that the statements essentially give the same result. To me it seems code 1 filters on the tenants address after the join and code 2 does the filtering within the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were an `INNER JOIN`, the queries would be equivalent. But since this is a `LEFT JOIN`, they are not. Say that `tenants` holds the tuple `id: 005, address: 'bla'`. The first query checks that the IDs match, performs the join, then sees that the addresses don't match, and omits the row. The second query doesn't join, because the addresses don't match, but doesn't omit the row, returning instead `NULL`s for all columns of `tenants`!

```sql
WITH houses (id) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (5)) as a
), tenants (id, address) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (5, 'bla')
         ) as tenants
)
SELECT *
FROM houses LEFT JOIN tenants ON houses.id = tenants.id
WHERE houses.id = 005 and tenants.address = '1 chavvy road';

WITH houses (id) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (5)) as a
), tenants (id, address) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (5, 'bla')
         ) as tenants
)
SELECT *
FROM houses LEFT JOIN tenants ON houses.id = tenants.id and tenants.address = '1 chavvy road'
WHERE houses.id = 005;
```